# Django get custom queryset into ListView

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, listview, django-views

I have a listview that I access in a pretty bog standard way to return all metaobjects.

```
#url 
url(r'^metaobject/$', MetaObjectList.as_view(),name='metaobject_list'),

#ListView
class MetaObjectList(ListView):
    model = MetaObject
```

I've recently added a search form that I want to scan my objects (I've got about 5 fields but I've simplified the example). What I'd like to do is re-use my MetaObjectList class view with my specific subset. I am guessing I need to override the get_queryset method but I'm not clear in how I get the queryset from my FormView into the listview. I mucked around a bit with calling the as_view() in the formveiw's form_valid function with additional parameters but couldn't get it to work and it seemed hacky anyway.

```
class SearchView(FormView):
    template_name = 'heavy/search.html'
    form_class = SearchForm

    #success_url = '/thanks/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        #build a queryset based on form
        searchval=form.cleaned_data['search']
        list = MetaObject.objects.filter(val=search)
        #where to from here?
```

I also looked at trying to post the data from the form view over to the listview but that seemed like I'd need to re-write the form logic into the listview.

I'm on python 3.x and django 1.11.

Comment: I think this would help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18664182/is-it-possible-to-have-a-form-in-a-listview-template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found what I feel is more elegant than the comment on the question:

My form valid now points to the list object's as_view method and passes the request and the queryset I want

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    #build a queryset based on form
    searchval=form.cleaned_data['search']
    list = MetaObject.objects.filter(val=search)
    return MetaObjectList.as_view()(self.request,list)
```

This hits the ListView as a post which I use to alter the queryset

```
class MetaObjectList(ListView):
    model = MetaObject

    queryset = MetaObject.objects.prefetch_related('object_type','domain')

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.queryset = args[0]
        return self.get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

The only obvious change is using kwargs to make it a bit clearer. Otherwise this seems to work well.